# uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have imported the Ionic 4 Android project into Android studio. But it shows below error. I can build the app using CLI: `ionic cordova build android --prod` and no issues. Any clue?

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be
>   smaller than version 19 declared in library
>   [**tested_artifact**::CordovaLib]
>   D:\Clients\ionic4\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 1     Suggestion: use
>   a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,      or increase this
>   project's minSdk version to at least 19,      or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to
>   runtime failures)

2nd error

```
    The minSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest file. You 
can move the version from the manifest to the defaultConfig in the build.gradle 
file. <a href="remove.sdk.from.manifest">Move minSdkVersion to build files and 
sync project</a> Affected Modules: <a 
href="openFile:D:/Clients/ionic4/platforms/android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml"
>CordovaLib</a>, <a 
href="openFile:D:/Clients/ionic4/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xm
l">app</a>
```

*config.xml*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.my.xos" version="0.2.8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>xos</name>
    <description>xos App</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">m-hospitality</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="Hostname" value="localhost:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100/*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
    </edit-config>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.1.1">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-ionic-xhr" spec="^2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="^2.1.1">
        <variable name="OKHTTP_VERSION" value="3.10.0" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="^3.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" spec="^3.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="^1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx" spec="^1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" spec="^1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-document-viewer" spec="^0.9.11" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="^2.2.1">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="5.0.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="8.0.0" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually one of your library has minsdk = 19 , thats why you can't use minsdk below 19 in you project.

So change minsdk to 19 and it will work fine.

Comment: How to find out the location of the file?

Comment: which file ? current or that library ?

Comment: do one thing remove minsdk.

Comment: Can you tell me where?

Comment: in build.gradle(module)